# Remove Nth Node From End of List LeetCode

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I'm doing the [Remove Nth Node from End of List](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/) LeetCode challenge:

> Given the `head` of a linked list, remove the `n`<sup>th</sup> node from the end of the list and return its head.
>
> **Follow up:** Could you do this in one pass?

My code is failing on some test cases:

> ```
> [1,2]
> 2
> ```

And I get this report:

> ```
> Output [1]
> Expected [2]
> ```

I've read the solutions already and it appears that my solution is the same as the one written, but I can't figure out where my mistake is. My code is as follows:

```py
def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: ListNode, n: int) -> ListNode:
    pointer1 = head
    pointer2 = head
    count = 0
    if not pointer1.next:
        return pointer1.next
    while pointer2 is not None:
        if count > n:
            pointer1 = pointer1.next
        pointer2 = pointer2.next
        count += 1
    pointer1.next = pointer1.next.next
    return head
```

I've been at this for half an hour now and I can't figure out hwo to fix it. Can someone please help?

Comment: Try this array as input - [1,2] and n is 2.  You will see what's going wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will fail when `n` is equal to the number of nodes in the list. In that case you are supposed to remove the first node from the list, and by consequence you should return `head.next`.

NB: the `if` you have before the `while` loop tests for a very specific instance of that case, i.e. when the list has just one element. But as explained above this action should apply in a more generic case than is identified in the `if`.

So, the following `if` condition could be dropped:

```py
if not pointer1.next:
    return pointer1.next
```

And add a condition *after* the `while` loop:

```py
def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: ListNode, n: int) -> ListNode:
    pointer1 = head
    pointer2 = head
    count = 0
    while pointer2 is not None:
        if count > n:
            pointer1 = pointer1.next
        pointer2 = pointer2.next
        count += 1
    if count > n:
        pointer1.next = pointer1.next.next
        return head  
    else:
        return head.next
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Greatly appreciated. I've accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing approaches in Java code snippets (in case anyone is interested for this problem)

***Approach #1***

Using two iterations - in the first iteration finding the total number of elements in the list to find the index of the element to delete from the beginning of the array and deleting it.

```
        public ListNode removeNthFromEnd(ListNode head, int n) {
        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (n < 0) {
            return head;
        }
        //find size of the list
        int size = 0;
        ListNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            size++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        if (n > size) {
            return head;
        }
        int indexOfTheElementToDelete = size - n;
        ListNode previous = null;
        current = head;
        int currentNodeIndex = 0;
        while (currentNodeIndex < indexOfTheElementToDelete) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
            currentNodeIndex++;
        }
        if (previous != null) {
            if (current != null) {
                previous.next = current.next;
                current.next = null;
            } else {
                // last element to delete
                previous.next = null;
            }
            return head;
        }
        // first element
        ListNode newHead = current.next;
        current.next = null;
        return newHead;
    }
```

***Approach #2***

1. It only traverses the list once
2. And to accomplish that the basic idea is to maintain two pointers which are always distanced by n (say slow and fast pointers). And moving both of them such that fast pointer reaches the end - the code snippet below has details.

   ```
       public ListNode removeNthFromEnd(ListNode head, int n) {
       if (head == null) {
           return null;
       }
       if (n <= 0) {
           return head;
       }
       ListNode start = new ListNode();
       start.next = head;
       ListNode slow = start;
       ListNode fast = head;
       int indexOfFastNode = 1;
       while (indexOfFastNode < n && fast.next != null) {
           fast = fast.next;
           indexOfFastNode++;
       }
       if (n > indexOfFastNode) {
           return head;
       }
       while (fast.next != null) {
           fast = fast.next;
           slow = slow.next;
       }
       ListNode temp = slow.next;
       slow.next = slow.next.next;
       temp.next = null;
       return start.next;
   }
   ```